# Date Converstion to days, hours, mins format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am converting diffrence between two dates in javascript to Days:Hours:Mins format.

```
<html>
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js""></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var today = new Date();
        var before = new Date();
        before.setDate(today.getDate() - 3);
        var diff = today.getTime() - before.getTime();

        var diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        var diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
        var diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        $('#days')[0].innerHTML = diffDays;
        $('#hours')[0].innerHTML = diffHours;
        $('#minutes')[0].innerHTML = diffMinutes;
        setInterval(myfunc,60000);              

        function myfunc(){              
            if(diff > 0){
                diff = diff - 60000;
                diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
                diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
                diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

                $('#days')[0].innerHTML = Math.floor(diffDays);
                $('#hours')[0].innerHTML = Math.floor(diffHours);
                $('#minutes')[0].innerHTML = diffMinutes;
            }
        }       
    });

</script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Days:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="days"></label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>Hours:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="hours"></label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>Mintues:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="minutes"></label>
        </td>           
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

When the difference is calculated it will be like Days : 2 Hours : 4 Minutes: 52

What i want is, if days or hours are in single digit, I want to append 0 before them.

How to do achieve that? Is it possible with regex or number formatting?

Comment: You'd better to use moment.js lib. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: There are many identical questions on SO, please search before asking.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). Check out the [Difference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) section. If for some reason you can't use a library, you can at least use their source code and derive your own solution.